# How does raster package convert text to number values on export to tif?

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff

Background:

- spatialpixelsdataframe with @data$column classifying the pixels into n categories
- the category column contains text data e.g. "Area A", "Area B" etc and is of factor type
- writing that information to GeoTIFF requires that the text names be converted to number values

writeRaster (or writeGDAL? or the GTiff driver?) seems to be able to do this without instruction. So it must decide how to assign numbers to those categories. I'm not sure how that's done. By factor level? Order of encounter as values are written out? I'd like to know for sure, because it affects how one writes lookup tables for the output tifs (Value 2 = "Area A" etc).

I'm aware that one could convert the categories to numbers in a new column before writing that to file, but I still want to know what happens if one doesn't.